# database/sql rows.scan hangs after 350K rows

Tags: go, large-data, large-data-volumes

I have a task to pull data from an Oracle Database and I am trying to pull huge data > 6MM records with 100 columns for processing.

Need to convert the data to a Map. I was successfully able to process them for 350K records in less than 35 seconds. After that the server hangs and does not proceed further.
Is there a way I can batch these based on the row size or batch them to free up my space.

```
func FetchUsingGenericResult(ctx context.Context, dsConnection *string, sqlStatement string) (*entity.GenericResultCollector, error) {
    columnTypes := make(map[string]string)
    var resultCollection entity.GenericResultCollector
    db, err := sql.Open("godror", *dsConnection)
    if err != nil {
        return &resultCollection, errors.Wrap(err, "error connecting to Oracle")
    }
    log := logger.FromContext(ctx).Sugar()
    log.Infof("start querying from Oracle at :%v", time.Now())
    rows, err := db.Query(sqlStatement, godror.FetchRowCount(defaultFetchCount))
    if err != nil {
        return &resultCollection, errors.Wrap(err, "error querying")
    }
    objects, err := rows2Strings(ctx, rows)
    log.Infof("total Rows converted are :%v by %v", len(*objects), time.Now())
    resultCollection = entity.GenericResultCollector{
        Columns: columnTypes,
        Rows:    objects,
    }
    return &resultCollection, nil
}

func rows2Strings(ctx context.Context, rows *sql.Rows) (*[]map[string]string, error) {
    result := make(map[string]string)
    resultsSlice := []map[string]string{}
    fields, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    log := logger.FromContext(ctx).Sugar()
    waitGroup, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)
    counter := 0
    for rows.Next() {
        counter++
        if counter%defaultFetchCount == 0 {
            log.Infof("finished converting %v rows by %v", counter, time.Now())
        }
        waitGroup.Go(func() error {
            result, err = row2mapStr(rows, fields)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            resultsSlice = append(resultsSlice, result)
            return nil
        })
        if err := waitGroup.Wait(); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    return &resultsSlice, nil
}

func row2mapStr(rows *sql.Rows, fields []string) (resultsMap map[string]string, err error) {
    result := make(map[string]string)
    scanResultContainers := make([]interface{}, len(fields))
    for i := 0; i < len(fields); i++ {
        var scanResultContainer interface{}
        scanResultContainers[i] = &scanResultContainer
    }
    if err := rows.Scan(scanResultContainers...); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for ii, key := range fields {
        rawValue := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(scanResultContainers[ii]))
        // if row is null then as empty string
        if rawValue.Interface() == nil {
            result[key] = ""
            continue
        }

        if data, err := value2String(&rawValue); err == nil {
            result[key] = data
        } else {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    return result, nil
}

func value2String(rawValue *reflect.Value) (str string, err error) {
    aa := reflect.TypeOf((*rawValue).Interface())
    vv := reflect.ValueOf((*rawValue).Interface())
    switch aa.Kind() {
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
        str = strconv.FormatInt(vv.Int(), 10)
    case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
        str = strconv.FormatUint(vv.Uint(), 10)
    case reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64:
        str = strconv.FormatFloat(vv.Float(), 'f', -1, 64)
    case reflect.String:
        str = vv.String()
    case reflect.Array, reflect.Slice:
        switch aa.Elem().Kind() {
        case reflect.Uint8:
            data := rawValue.Interface().([]byte)
            str = string(data)
            if str == "\x00" {
                str = "0"
            }
        default:
            err = fmt.Errorf("Unsupported struct type %v", vv.Type().Name())
        }
    // time type
    case reflect.Struct:
        if aa.ConvertibleTo(timeType) {
            str = vv.Convert(timeType).Interface().(time.Time).Format(time.RFC3339Nano)
        } else {
            err = fmt.Errorf("Unsupported struct type %v", vv.Type().Name())
        }
    case reflect.Bool:
        str = strconv.FormatBool(vv.Bool())
    case reflect.Complex128, reflect.Complex64:
        str = fmt.Sprintf("%v", vv.Complex())
    default:
        err = fmt.Errorf("Unsupported struct type %v", vv.Type().Name())
    }
    return
}
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Modified the code as below:

```
func FetchUsingGenericResult(ctx context.Context, dsConnection *string, sqlStatement string) (*entity.GenericResultCollector, error) {
    columnTypes := make(map[string]string)
    var resultCollection entity.GenericResultCollector
    db, err := sql.Open("godror", *dsConnection)
    if err != nil {
        return &resultCollection, errors.Wrap(err, "error connecting to Oracle")
    }
    log := logger.FromContext(ctx).Sugar()
    log.Infof("start querying from Oracle at :%v", time.Now())
    rows, err := db.Query(sqlStatement, godror.FetchRowCount(defaultFetchCount))
    if err != nil {
        return &resultCollection, errors.Wrap(err, "error querying")
    }
    objects, err := rows2Strings(ctx, rows)
    log.Infof("total Rows converted are :%v by %v", len(*objects), time.Now())
    resultCollection = entity.GenericResultCollector{
        Columns: columnTypes,
        Rows:    objects,
    }
    return &resultCollection, nil
}

func rows2Strings(ctx context.Context, rows *sql.Rows) (*[]map[string]string, error) {
    result := make(map[string]string)
    resultsSlice := []map[string]string{}
    fields, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    log := logger.FromContext(ctx).Sugar()
    counter := 0
    for rows.Next() {
        counter++
        if counter%defaultFetchCount == 0 {
            log.Infof("finished converting %v rows by %v", counter, time.Now())
        }
        result, err = row2mapStr(rows, fields)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        resultsSlice = append(resultsSlice, result)
    }
    return &resultsSlice, nil
}

func row2mapStr(rows *sql.Rows, fields []string) (resultsMap map[string]string, err error) {
    result := make(map[string]string)
    scanResultContainers := make([]interface{}, len(fields))
    for i := 0; i < len(fields); i++ {
        var scanResultContainer interface{}
        scanResultContainers[i] = &scanResultContainer
    }
    if err := rows.Scan(scanResultContainers...); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for ii, key := range fields {
        rawValue := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(scanResultContainers[ii]))
        // if row is null then as empty string
        if rawValue.Interface() == nil {
            result[key] = ""
            continue
        }

        if data, err := value2String(&rawValue); err == nil {
            result[key] = data
        } else {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    return result, nil
}

func value2String(rawValue *reflect.Value) (str string, err error) {
    aa := reflect.TypeOf((*rawValue).Interface())
    vv := reflect.ValueOf((*rawValue).Interface())
    switch aa.Kind() {
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
        str = strconv.FormatInt(vv.Int(), 10)
    case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
        str = strconv.FormatUint(vv.Uint(), 10)
    case reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64:
        str = strconv.FormatFloat(vv.Float(), 'f', -1, 64)
    case reflect.String:
        str = vv.String()
    case reflect.Array, reflect.Slice:
        switch aa.Elem().Kind() {
        case reflect.Uint8:
            data := rawValue.Interface().([]byte)
            str = string(data)
            if str == "\x00" {
                str = "0"
            }
        default:
            err = fmt.Errorf("Unsupported struct type %v", vv.Type().Name())
        }
    // time type
    case reflect.Struct:
        if aa.ConvertibleTo(timeType) {
            str = vv.Convert(timeType).Interface().(time.Time).Format(time.RFC3339Nano)
        } else {
            err = fmt.Errorf("Unsupported struct type %v", vv.Type().Name())
        }
    case reflect.Bool:
        str = strconv.FormatBool(vv.Bool())
    case reflect.Complex128, reflect.Complex64:
        str = fmt.Sprintf("%v", vv.Complex())
    default:
        err = fmt.Errorf("Unsupported struct type %v", vv.Type().Name())
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: What is the `waitGroup` stuff? This is sequential row processing code, what is there a need for that? Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @BurakSerdar The waitGroup is coded it enforces sequential processing. He is doing a wait immediately after Go. Which means that there would be only one go routine for which it would be waiting. For me bigger issue is amount of generalization built into code. A small query to identify types of columns and targeting those types would reduce code size significantly.

Comment: @praveent I see nothing in the code that can cause the described behavior except the waitGroup stuff, and maybe somehow some server side problem. My first instinct would be to remove waitgroup related code. Reading rows from a database in a for loop does not need a separate goroutine.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I agree. waitGroup does not add anything to the code. The way it is written is a roundabout manner to write sequential code.

Comment: @praveent After removing the wait group event after > 10 mins I cannot see 100K records processing.

Comment: Also you should check for `rows.Err()` after the iteration is done. Maybe there is an error what prevents you from iterating further. Also, I'd suggest you, in general, to avoid loading huge arrays of data into memory. It's better to process the data as you scan it.

Comment: There is couple of more things to fix: 1) You don't need reflection to check the actual type of an `interface{}`. Just use type switch. 2) For the most your value to string could be a simple `fmt.Sprint(v)`

Comment: @MaximKosov I was trying to process the data as I scan but we use MVCS framework so could not call a higher level gateway from another gateway.
I was under the impression fmt.Sprint(v) would take bigger space than reflect. Let me try that out and get back.

Comment: This is a space issue on the server side. I changed the logic to process the data as I scan. Thanks @MaximKosov

Answer (score 0):

As the server memory was limited the array could was stuck without proceeding further.
I have started process the data as it gets scanned and this solved my problem.